# ERC721 - Create 1000 tokens in one function call

Tags: contract-development, erc-721, nft

I have implemented a contract where a set of ERC721 tokens should be generated with a function call in private net. Code as follows :

```
function mint(
    address _owner,
    uint256[] _id
)
    onlyOwner
    external
    returns (uint256)
{
    for(uint i = 0; i<_id.length; i++){
        super._mint(_owner, _id[i]);
    }
}
```

It creates up to 33 ERC721 Tokens, then the gas hits the gasLimit and loop ends. I am running it on my private net with genesis file as follows:

```
{
  "config": {
  "chainId": PrivateNetworkID,
 "homesteadBlock": 0,
  "eip155Block": 0,
  "eip158Block": 0
},
"alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance": "111111111"},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {"balance": "222222222"}
},
"coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData"  : "",
"gasLimit"   : "0x8880000",
"nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash"    : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

JS :

```
MyNFToken.deployed().then(function (instance) {

 //randomtoken - Array containing 33 tokenID
  return instance.mint(account, randomtoken, { from: account, gas: 4600000 }).then(function (result) {

    console.log('Result = ' + JSON.stringify(result));

  })
});
```

In js if I change the gas:4600000 to a higher value, **gaslimit exceeds** error occurs.

How can I resolve this?Is it possible to create at least 1000 tokens in a function call? Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please explain your use case. Will you be doing this one time or periodically?

Comment: **Need more information:** How much gas is each create token loop call consuming and what is the gas limit on the network you are on? Assuming you're on Ethereum mainnet the gas limit is 8000000. That would mean your 33 calls are using roughly 240K in gas each. You would hit the gas limit and get the out of gas error message.

Comment: Thanks...I have added the genesis file above.I tried --targetgaslimit '9000000000000' on the command initiating private net node, but still I'm getting **exceeds gaslimit** error

Comment: Loops are bound to fail on Ethereum due to gas limits and transaction timeouts. If you want check out https://www.cargo.build. You can mint 2^255 ERC-721 tokens at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess the problem got resolved :). I changed gaslimit : '9000000000000' in the genesis file. Doesn't know whether it is the correct way of doing it. Though it take a bit ether, tokens are created in bulk amount. Since it is a private net, consuming ether is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of today 2019-01-25 in mainnet the block gas limit is 8M. If minting a single token consumes 50K gas then you can at most create 160 tokens.

```
 8000000 / 50000 = 160
```

If you have to mint 1000 tokens I'd suggest to try a different approach. For example you can store only the root of the merkle tree of the new tokens. If someone wants to redeem tokens they submit the path of the token in the merkle tree, and after validation the tokens is added to their account.

Comment: Thanks Ismael...Can you explain a bit more about the solution.Is there any documentation?

Comment: There's an article doing something similar for airdrops from RicMoo https://blog.ricmoo.com/merkle-air-drops-e6406945584d

Answer (score 1):

This technique was presented on stage at NFT.nft by yours truly using a combination of ERC-721, ERC-998 (ish) and ERC-1167.

Also the technique is explained in Su Squares at https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract

It is surely too much code to paste in this answer so I'll summarize:

- You can only create N tokens at once efficiently during contract creation
- Don't be afraid of creating contracts to create tokens
- Contracts can be created efficiently using the proxy standard

The presentation is available at http://nft.life

Comment: Hi - by any chance, were any files/links removed from your `net.life` website? Cause I didn't find any actual code samples about batch minting. Same for the GitHub repo. I'm specifically talking about the actual code that does the actual MINTING of these 10,000 su-squares. I'm pretty sure l looked through every single folder there (nice project by the way!)  So where/how is this batch minting actually happening?

Comment: Thank you. It's in the initialize function.

Comment: Are you talking about the `constructor` function in `SuNFT.sol`? Cause while I see 3 different `for` loops in there - all iterating up to `TOTAL_SUPPLY`, they're all commented out. So I can't tell if or which of them was ever executed. Also, none of these `for` loops have a call to the `mint` function in them, so I'm further confused. Where's the minting happening?

Comment: The for loops are commented out because they would use O(N) gas and they produce the same effect as the latter line of code which runs in O(1).

Comment: In terms of giving each Token a *truly unique* URI, your approach (this: `_tokenURIBytes[33] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 10000) % 10);` etc)  won't really work for any application other than yours. I mean it's very clever, but has very limited usage. Which is why you also provided that `personalizeSquare()` function. It's only by using *it* that Token owners can provide *truly* unique metadata - such as their `href` - which is something you couldn't really do programmatically. And this they can only do AFTER minting their NFT, and only buy paying an additional fee.

Comment: Metadata is outside the scope of this question. Yes, the Su Squares approach is extensible to other applications, but the exact code is not. That's how I get clients.

Comment: Ah yes, Clients! Of course  I wasn't knocking your approach by the way, on the contrary, I actually LOVE your `SuNFT` Contract. It’s kinda mind-blowingly refreshing. See, I’ve gotten so used to working with/from `OpenZeppelin’s ERC721 Contract` - particularly their `_mint()` and `setTokenURI()` functions, I’ve forgotten theirs is NOT the only way to implement the `IERC721 Interface` (which doesn’t even require writing `mint()` and `setTokenURI()`!). Your `SuNFT` reminded me there are other ways to make a compliant `ERC721` contract so it's been particularly sobering & inspiring!